# If $A\subset M$, then there is no $B\neq\emptyset$ such that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Tags: real-analysis

Clarification: If $A\subset M$ where $M$ is the only closed set such that this is true, then there is no open set $B\neq\emptyset$ such that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

I started with the contradiction where I assumed there was such an open non-empty $B$ that is disjoint from $A$. But then I have no idea how to proceed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say $B$ is such a set. Hint: what can you say about the complement of $B$? What kind of set is it? And how does it relate to $A$ (in terms of inclusion relation)?

Comment: $B^c$ is a closed set that contains A. That is, $A\subset B^c$, but since the only closed set that contains $A$ is $M$, $B^c=M$, which I can use to arrive at a contradiction. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $B^c=M$ means that $B=\varnothing$, so that's the contradiction.

Comment: Any contradiction will do. Yes, we started with multiple assumptions -- that $M$ is the only closed set containing $A$, that $B\neq\varnothing$, and that $A\cap B=\varnothing$. But you don't need to arrive at all possible contradictions, not at all. Assuming $B\neq\varnothing$ and arriving at $B=\varnothing$ is already a contradiction, isn't it?